# Picasso image loading previously cached images

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, image-loading, image-caching

I am using picasso library in my project to fetch url images from the server into my ImageView, but unfortunately picasso loading the previously cached images from disc instead of loading the new images from url. Please find the below piece of code for your reference.

```
Picasso.with (ImageActivity.this)
                    .load(url)
                    .placeholder (R.drawable.default_user)
                    .error (R.drawable.default_user)
                    .into(imgUser);
```

I have also tried the solutions like:

```
Picasso.with(ImageActivity.this).invalidate(url);
```

and

```
Picasso.with (ImageActivity.this)
                            .load(url).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                            .placeholder (R.drawable.default_user)
                            .error (R.drawable.default_user)
                            .into(imgUser);
```

But nothing is working for me. Kindly help me to resolve my issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so every time you want to load a new image and not store in the cache?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try :

```
  Picasso.with(mContext)
        .load(URL)
        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE )
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
        .error(R.drawable.xxx)
        .into(xx);
```

Comment: Is there a Solution for exact inverse of it. I want to load images only from Cache even if there is Connection. Because I wan't to have a Settings that disables Image Loading to save data

Answer (score -1):

I know there's already an answer but after trying a few ways I figured out a very simple way: 
Check if the image is null - if it is not - then load the image with Picasso-like that:

```
if(vImage.getDrawable() == null)
Picasso.with(context).load(URL).into(vImage);
```

Hope this helped someone.